# JMustache labelled Butterknife in Android app's About

Tags: bug, android-app

There are two Butterknives in the About dialogue of the official Stack Exchange app for Android. They differ by URL, though.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G357FZ

  - OS Version: 4.4.4 (G357FZXXU1AOG1)

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. The app leads me much less than the full aweb in this regard.

Comment: One of those tiny minor bugs that will never get fixed. (in this case, because there's nobody to fix it.)